# pip list shows packages installed but cannot import in Python

Tags: python, import, pip, spyder

Using Spyder and set up spdyer miniconda environment in Python and connected to that environment.  pip list shows my packages are installed but I cannot import them.

I get the error below.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "package name"
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message, It would be easier for anyone to help you if you do.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think your problem is you installed your packages in a different Python environment. Please read [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to learn how to connect that environments to Spyder.

Comment: I followed spyder instructions and set up spyder environment with miniconda and changed my default environment in spyder to this environment.  problem is still present

Comment: this is the setup that I followed   https://youtu.be/i7Njb3xO4Fw

Comment: figured it out. I think a simple restart of spyder resolved the issue.  The new envirornment was still running the only env despite changing my default environment.  thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.